# Unable to see Selenium Grid running when viewed from browser

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have started selenium hub using docker commands , and when I have used command :

`docker logs -t containerId`

I see the below info:

```
2017-06-18T11:16:52.627304034Z 11:16:52.626 INFO - Nodes should register to http://172.17.0.2:4444/grid/register/

2017-06-18T11:16:52.627306649Z 11:16:52.626 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running

2017-06-18T11:43:00.429659817Z 11:43:00.429 INFO - Registered a node http://172.17.0.3:5555
```

However, when I access `http://172.17.0.2:4444/grid` , I am getting Page not found error.

I have even tried accessing (the default machine IP as per docker) `:http://192.168.99.100:4444/` , but the same error.

What am I missing to  access Selenium Gird home page?

Comment: The Grid URL is http://IP:port/grid/console. Doesn't that work ? Here IP is supposed to be the machine on which your Docker container is running and port is supposed to be the port that is exposed. On what flavor are you running your docker container ?

Comment: I am using Docker tool kit on windows 10 home.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like i am bit late, For however have a solution for it.
While running Docker in Windows 10, Rather than using LocalHost please use the system IP.

`$ docker-machine ip`

Grid URL will be something like

`http://YourSystemIP:4444/grid/console`

Regards
geek